# Performance tuning for linq/lambda expression

Tags: c#, performance, lambda, performance-testing

I have some line of code as below.

```
string result = listDetails
    .Where(filename => filename.Contains(fullname)).FirstOrDefault().Split('\\')
    .Where(name => name.Contains(nameGivenToSearch)).FirstOrDefault();

if (result.Contains("sd"))
    // Do something
```

While running a tool for checking the performance it shows the performance warning in above statement.

I want to make this more performance feasible. I have heard that nested lambda expression is slower in executing.

Please suggest something to counter this or any link that will be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to do, in plain english?

Comment: Could you write the requirement you need to meet? Currently you're showing how you're getting something, it might be easier if you say what you want to get.

Comment: This code wont compile: No overload for method 'Contains' takes 0 arguments

Comment: It is searching the filename where fullname is present the spliting the result by "\\" then again seraching something in the first resulatant string data

Comment: i have edited the Contain section

Comment: Which 'tool' are you running?

Comment: Seems like the code is supposed to get a file that either is named "sd" or is in a folder named "sd"? The linq query expression maybe does accomplish this but it seems rather awkwardly written. You could probably optimize it by writing it differently. Please tell us what it is supposed to do, how large a list it searches and how often this code is supposed to run and we may be able to help you optimize.

Comment: You can replace `.Where(...).FirstOrDefault()` by `.FirstOrDefault(...)`. This might slightly improve performance.

Comment: @mortb: there are many query,accomplishing different kind of task in different situation. The query is executed only once for one execution. The list may be  of 1000 entried max.

Answer (score 0):

Try caching the data searched (or all of it, before your app starts) into the [Dictionary<,>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as:

```
string result = listDetails.FirstOrDefault(filename => filename.Contains(fullname));
if (result != null)
    result = result.Split('\\').FirstOrDefault(name => name.Contains(namegiventosearch));
if (result != null && result.Contains("sd"))
{
     //do task
}
```

I don't think there is much room for performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct that the list contains paths to files I think the main problem is that you split the path to get the filename. Use functions `Path.GetDirectoryName` and `Path.GetFileName` instead. Searching a list of max 1000 string entries should not be to processor heavy

```
    if (listDetails.Where(x => { if(Path.GetDirectoryName(x).Contains(fullname))
                                 {
                                    var file = Path.GetFileName(x);
                                    return file.Contains(namegiventosearch) && file.Contains("sd");
                                 }
                                 else 
                                 {
                                    return false;
                             }
    }).FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
         // do Task
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: Using `Count() > 0` instead of `Any()` can significantly hurt performance.

Comment: good point, editing to FirstOrDefault, which will not enumerate the whole list, instead